# Emit not working for web sockets in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, websocket

I have integrated web sockets in my iOS app. The server is written with `Nodejs` and `express`. Apart from my iOS app I also have a `reactjs` web app. The web app works correctly so there is no issue from server side. I am using this library for my iOS app https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/

Now I am able to receive events from my server like if a new user has joined in the iOS app but the iOS app won't emit any event on button click. On viewdidload I have an emit event of userjoin which works perfectly. But when I am sending message on a button click that event does not work. Here is a gist of my code

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "MY_URL")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    var socket: SocketIOClient? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        socket = manager.defaultSocket

socket?.connect()

        socket?.on("connect") { _, _ in
            self.socket?.emit("userjoin", self.defaults.string(forKey:"email") ?? "")
        }

        socket?.on("userjoined", callback: { (data, ack) in
            self.userJoinedLbl.text = data[0] as? String ?? ""
        }) ...
```

The above code works perfectly fine. Below code of my button click won't work

```
@IBAction func sendMsgClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        debugPrint(self.defaults.string(forKey:"id") ?? "")
        socket?.on("connect") { _, _ in
            self.socket?.emit("sendMessage", self.sendMsgTextField.text ?? "",self.defaults.string(forKey:"id") ?? "")
        }

    }
```

I am getting following logs from the web socket library

```
2020-04-05 15:09:58.032340+0530 WebSocketNativeIOS[5995:216223] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: connect
2020-04-05 15:10:17.211199+0530 WebSocketNativeIOS[5995:216223] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: ping with data: []
2020-04-05 15:10:17.211211+0530 WebSocketNativeIOS[5995:218688] LOG SocketEngine: Writing ws:  has data: false
2020-04-05 15:10:17.211587+0530 WebSocketNativeIOS[5995:218688] LOG SocketEngineWebSocket: Sending ws:  as type: 2
2020-04-05 15:10:17.418903+0530 WebSocketNativeIOS[5995:218688] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 3
2020-04-05 15:10:17.419593+0530 WebSocketNativeIOS[5995:216223] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: pong with data: []
```

I am emitting an sendMessage event which takes the user message and user id. The user message and user id are not null. The sendMessage event works fine on the web app

The code for my web app when the button is clicked is

```
socket.emit("sendMessage", msg, localStorage.getItem("userId"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out

I added this in my button click

```
manager.defaultSocket.emit("sendMessage", self.sendMsgTextField.text ?? "",self.defaults.string(forKey:"id") ?? "")
```

Thanks to this issue https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/issues/1055 I was able to figure it out